# Assigning char type to int to print corresponding ASCII character

Tags: c++, char, int, ascii

The code asks for a positive integer, than the first output shows the corresponding ASCII code, the others are made to convert the integer to decimal, octal and hexadecimal equivalents. I understand the logic of the code, but I don't understand the assignment made on line 10 `c=code` than the assignment made on line 12 `code=c`. What happens on background when we 'swap' the two variables.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    unsigned char c = 0;
    unsigned int code = 0;
    cout << "\nPlease enter a decimal character code: ";
    cin >> code;
    c = code; 
    cout << "\nThe corresponding character: " << c << endl;
    code = c; 
    cout << "\nCharacter codes"
    << "\n decimal: " << setw(3) << dec << code
    << "\n octal: " << setw(3) << oct << code
    << "\n hexadecimal: " << setw(3) << hex << code
    << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So it's about the number of bits that represent a type. A `char` is (at least, but almost always exactly) 8 bits. An `int` is at least 16 bits, but more often 32 bits. By assigning an `int` to a `char`, 32-8=24 bits are dropped in an implicit type conversion.  This will often result in a "loss of precision" compiler warning by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a swap. `c` is assigned the same value as `code` and then this value is assigned back to `code`. The original value of `code` is lost.

We can see this because `unsigned char c` is (usually) much smaller than `unsigned int code` and some information may be lost stuffing the value in `code` into `c`.

For example, `code` = 257. After `c = code;` `code` is still 257 and `c`, assuming an 8 bit `char` will be 1. After `code = c;`, both `code` and `c` will be 1. 257 has been lost.

Why is this being done? when given a `char`, `operator<<` will print out the character encoded, completely ignoring the request to print as `hex`, `dec`, or `oct`. So

```
<< "\n decimal: " << setw(3) << dec << c
```

is wasted.  Given an `int` `<<` will respect the modifiers, but if `c` and `code` have different values, you're comparing apples and Sasquatches.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong here so maybe someone else can weigh in, but I believe I know the answer.

If you assign a character a number, when you print that `char` it prints the corresponding character. Since `c` is of type `char`, the line `c = code` converts the integer entered into a character. You can test this yourself by assigning any `int` to a `char` variable and printing it out.

The second assignment, `code = c`, seems to be completely unnecessary.